# Proving $lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (I+\frac{H^*H}{\delta})^{-1} = 0$

Tags: matrices

Let $H$be an arbitrary complex matrix and $H^*$ is its conjugate transpose. How one can prove that $$lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \bigg(I+\frac{H^*H}{\delta}\bigg)^{-1} = 0$$

Could anyone give me hints?

Comment: This is not generally true. As an extreme case, consider $H = 0$ and notice that the limit is $I$ in this case. In general, it turns out that the limit is the orthogonal projection onto the kernel of $H$. You may use spectral theorem, for instance, to prove this.

Comment: $lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \bigg(I+\frac{H^*H}{\delta}\bigg)^{-1} = lim_{\delta \to 0^+}{\delta} \bigg({\delta}I+H^*H\bigg)^{-1} =lim_{\delta \to 0^+}\delta. lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \bigg({\delta}I+H^*H\bigg)^{-1}=0$ ?

Comment: How do you know that the limit $\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} (\delta I + H^*H)^{-1}$ converge? Again, in the extreme case $H = 0$ this does not converge. In analogy (and in fact more than just analogy in view of the spectral theorem), consider the computation $$\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \left(1 + \frac{c}{\delta}\right)^{-1} = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } c = 0 \\ 0, & \text{if } c > 0 \end{cases}. $$